# Data animation bootstrap carousel effects is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i have implemented data animation effect in my slider but the animation effect is not working after implementing in my project.it is displaying all the images as a single slide and the slider also not moving for the first time.If we click on next and previous buttons then the slider is moving automatically if not it is not accepting.Here is my code.While implementing in my project got error as

Uncaught TypeError: $myCarousel.carousel is not a function

```js
  (function( $ ) {
//Function to animate slider captions 
function doAnimations( elems ) {
    //Cache the animationend event in a variable
    var animEndEv = 'webkitAnimationEnd animationend';

    elems.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $animationType = $this.data('animation');
        $this.addClass($animationType).one(animEndEv, function () {
            $this.removeClass($animationType);
        });
    });
}

//Variables on page load 
var $myCarousel = $('#carousel-example-generic'),
    $firstAnimatingElems = $myCarousel.find('.item:first').find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");

//Initialize carousel 
$myCarousel.carousel();

//Animate captions in first slide on page load 
doAnimations($firstAnimatingElems);

//Pause carousel  
$myCarousel.carousel('pause');


//Other slides to be animated on carousel slide event 
$myCarousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var $animatingElems = $(e.relatedTarget).find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");
    doAnimations($animatingElems);
});  
$('#carousel-example-generic').carousel({
    interval:3000,
    pause: "false"
});

 })(jQuery);
```

```css
#first-slider .main-container {
padding: 0;
}
#first-slider .slide1 h3, #first-slider .slide2 h3, #first-slider .slide3 h3, #first-slider .slide4 h3{
color: #fff;
font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight:700;
}
#first-slider .slide1 h4,#first-slider .slide2 h4,#first-slider .slide3 h4,#first-slider .slide4 h4{
color: #fff;
font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight:700;
 }
 #first-slider .slide1 .text-left ,#first-slider .slide3 .text-left{
padding-left: 40px;
}
#first-slider .carousel-indicators {
bottom: 0;
}
#first-slider .carousel-control.right,
#first-slider .carousel-control.left {
background-image: none;
}
#first-slider .carousel .item {
 min-height: 425px; 
height: 100%;
width:100%;
}
 .carousel-inner .item .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
 }
  #first-slider h3{
  animation-delay: 1s;
  }
  #first-slider h4 {
  animation-delay: 2s;
  }
  #first-slider h2 {
  animation-delay: 3s;
  }
  #first-slider .carousel-control {
  width: 6%;
  text-shadow: none;
  }
  #first-slider h1 {
  text-align: center;  
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  }
  #first-slider .p {
  padding-top: 125px;
  text-align: center;
  }
  #first-slider .p a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  }
  #first-slider .carousel-indicators li {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
  border:none;
  }
  #first-slider .carousel-indicators .active{
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border:none;
  }
 .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
 -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
  transition-property: opacity;
  }
 .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item,
 .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
 .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
 opacity: 0;
}
  .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active,
  .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
  .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
  }
 .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next,
 .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev,
 .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
 .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
   left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
   .carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
  }
 .carousel-control .fa-angle-right, .carousel-control .fa-angle-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 5;
  display: inline-block;
  }
 .carousel-control .fa-angle-left{
 left: 50%;
width: 38px;
height: 38px;
margin-top: -15px;
font-size: 30px;
color: #fff;
border: 3px solid #ffffff;
-webkit-border-radius: 23px;
-moz-border-radius: 23px;
border-radius: 53px;
 }
.carousel-control .fa-angle-right{
right: 50%;
width: 38px;
height: 38px;
margin-top: -15px;
font-size: 30px;
color: #fff;
border: 3px solid #ffffff;
-webkit-border-radius: 23px;
-moz-border-radius: 23px;
border-radius: 53px;
}
.carousel-control {
opacity: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
#first-slider .slide1 {
background-image: url(http://s20.postimg.org/h50tgcuz1/image.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
 #first-slider .slide2 {
  background-image: url(http://s20.postimg.org/uxf8bzlql/image.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  #first-slider .slide3 {
  background-image: url(http://s20.postimg.org/el56m97f1/image.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  #first-slider .slide4 {
  background-image: url(http://s20.postimg.org/66pjy66dp/image.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bootcss.com/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.min.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="first-slider">
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <!-- Item 1 -->
        <div class="item active slide1">
            <div class="row"><div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
                    <img style="max-width: 200px;"  data-animation="animated zoomInLeft" src="http://s20.postimg.org/pfmmo6qj1/window_domain.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9 text-left">
                    <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInDown">Add images, or even your logo!</h3>
                    <h4 data-animation="animated bounceInUp">Easily use stunning effects</h4>             
                 </div>
            </div></div>
         </div> 
        <!-- Item 2 -->
        <div class="item slide2">
            <div class="row"><div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-7 text-left">
                    <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInDown"> 50 animation options A beautiful</h3>
                    <h4 data-animation="animated bounceInUp">Create beautiful slideshows </h4>
                 </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
                    <img style="max-width: 200px;"  data-animation="animated zoomInLeft" src="http://s20.postimg.org/sp11uneml/rack_server_unlock.png">
                </div>
            </div></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Item 3 -->
        <div class="item slide3">
            <div class="row"><div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-7 text-left">
                    <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInDown">Simple Bootstrap Carousel</h3>
                    <h4 data-animation="animated bounceInUp">Bootstrap Image Carousel Slider with Animate.css</h4>
                 </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
                    <img style="max-width: 200px;"  data-animation="animated zoomInLeft" src="http://s20.postimg.org/eq8xvxeq5/globe_network.png">
                </div>     
            </div></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Item 4 -->
        <div class="item slide4">
            <div class="row"><div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-7 text-left">
                    <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInDown">We are creative</h3>
                    <h4 data-animation="animated bounceInUp">Get start your next awesome project</h4>
                 </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
                    <img style="max-width: 200px;"  data-animation="animated zoomInLeft" src="http://s20.postimg.org/9vf8xngel/internet_speed.png">
                </div>  
            </div></div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Item 4 -->

    </div>
    <!-- End Wrapper for slides-->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i><span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i><span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Individually it is working fine while we implement this in a project it is not working as i have implemented in my online project.

Comment: Implementing in my project getting error as 

Uncaught TypeError: $myCarousel.carousel is not a function

Comment: Your snippet works as it should normally.. the error you get "Uncaught TypeError" is simply telling you that the function $myCarousel.carousel is missing. Check your JS imports and if you are calling the carousel function too early.

Comment: Include your scripts at bottom of your body element, and make sure you are not referencing jQuery twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including scripts after the html,

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i><span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i><span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/your/custom.js"></script>
```